# JavaScript - load PDF file from URL (cross domain) into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pdf

I would like to load PDF file from URL into JavaScript variable (this file is on another domain) and then print the base64 encoded string of that file.

This script allows me to browse file on my computer and then it prints base64 string into browser console:

```
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertToBase64() {
        //Read File
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
        //Check File is not Empty
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
            // Select the very first file from list
            var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
            // FileReader function for read the file.
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var base64;
            // Onload of file read the file content
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                // Print data in console
                console.log(base64);
            };
            // Convert data to base64
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like to completely remove the input button from this script and pass my file to variable `var selectedFile` from URL (for example: http://www.example.com/docs/document.pdf).

I'd need a help how to realize this, because I am not sure if `XMLHttpRequest()` works cross domain and scripts I've found with Ajax/jQuery method operated mainly with JSON file, which is something different that I need.

Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this in normal browser-based JavaScript* if the other side (`http://www.example.com` in your case) doesn't allow [cross-origin requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) from your origin.

If the other side *does* let you do this, then yes, you'd use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (or jQuery's wrappers for it, such as [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) to request the data and transform/display it as you see fit.

A fairly typical way to work around that if the other side doesn't is to use your own server in-between: Make the request to *your* server, have it make the request to the other side (server-side code doesn't have the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) blocks that browsers impose), and then have your server respond to your request with the data from the other server.

---

* "normal browser-based JavaScript" - e.g., without starting the browser with special flags that disable security, or getting people to install an extension, etc.